# x86 assembly instruction execution count

Tags: c, profiling, branch, x86, emulation

Hello everyone
I have a code and I want to find the number of times each assembly line executed. I dont care whether through profiling or emulation, yet I want high precision results. I came across a forum once that gave some scripting code to do so, yet I lost the link. Can anyone help me brainstorm some ways to do so?
Regards

**Edit**: 
Okey I think I am halfway there. I have done some research on the BTS (Branch Trace Store) provided by Intel Manual 3A section 16.4.5 according to one the posts. This feature provides branch history. So now I need your help to find if there are any open source scripts or tools to do this. Waiting to check your feedback

cheers=)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your processor supports it, you can enable Branch Trace Store (BTS).  BTS stores a log of all of the taken branches in a predefined area in memory.  Each entry contains the branch source and destination.  Using that, you can count how many times you were in each code segment.

Look at [volume 3A](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/253668.pdf) of the [Intel Software Developer's Manual](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/), section 16.4.5 (in the current edition) for details on how to enable it.

Comment: that sounds interesting! do you know of any software that uses it or do I have to code it myself? but still I think it won't be enough cause I would be neglecting the conditional statements!

Comment: @Syntax: I don't know if there are any packages that implement it.  What conditional statements would you be neglecting?

Comment: if you have cmova opcode this is a conditional move so it will only execute if the correct flags are raised. so even if it is within a function it won't always execute

Comment: @Syntax: It will *always* execute. There is no way for you to count instructions that will skip conditional moves in which the condition didn't hold.

Comment: That sounds gd I will try to find packages that read the BTS..if you find any let me know!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care about performance, you can do a small trick to count that. Raise a single step exception and upon entering your custom seh handler, raise another one and step over to the next command.

Maybe some profiler tools like pin or valgrind do that for you in an easier manner. I would suggest that you take a look.

Comment: I will look into pin! have u used it be4?

Comment: i have not used it extensively, but i have used it yes. Also, i have used the other technique with the single step to create some code that runs backwards. That is why i propose this method, where it's easy to count commands that you execute.

Answer (score 1):

One (although slow) method would be to write your own debugger. It would then breakpoint the entry point of your program, and when it was hit it would set the trace flag on the EFlags in the context, so it would break to the debugger on the next instruction as well. You could then use a hash table with the EIP to count the number of times hit.
Only problem is that the overhead would be extreme and the application would run very slowly.